# Make Images the same size, and not will be distorted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want my all images from my instafeed will all be the same size, shouldn't be distorted and image will resize freely (responsive), and i want it to look exactly like this: [instagram images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxeXl.jpg) , we can zoom the image a bit and make overflow hidden, its just i dont know the tricks :)

here is my work: http://jsfiddle.net/jazzu20/1c9yf61x/

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    
}

.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.livery-instafeed-section {
    min-height: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="livery-instafeed-section col-md-12">
   <div id="instafeed">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9JOiOdMLo5/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11251638_621920521284538_937019183_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9Gp4RjMLgE/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/1390058_175285799480082_576833592_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9FJpd7MLts/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12093236_443227142549068_286565452_n.jpg">            
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9D_lqkMLqV/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12145135_1069396733117579_706096349_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9Bb92JMLhh/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12093429_1668694736699760_1827692759_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/9ACbbHMLlD/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12135431_1733638416868070_1024332902_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/8_BXkSsLn5/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12105054_849750965144841_2082888771_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding:0;">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/p/89fRuosLje/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12107557_866233773472414_1869843871_n.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/jazzu20/1c9yf61x/

Comment: you images are squared (like 100x100px) and have white borders to the top-bottom or left-right. To make what you want you must make 1 of 2 things: 1. Get new squared images whithout white space. 2. Change `<img>` tags to `div` and use `background-url` to set images, and than play with `background-position` and `background-size` etc css properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1c9yf61x/1/).

Explanation of what happens here:

First of all, I've moved the images to be a background image of the anchor (`<a>`) tag. That gives you a lot more flexibility, because you can make use of the `background-position` and `background-size` properties.

Next I've positioned the anchor `absolute` (and the column `relative` to make sure the anchor is taking account of it's parents size) and made it as heigh and wide as the column.

Now you have the same width, but not the same height, as the column doesn't have a height from itself. Giving it a percentual height doesn't help you, because that would be relative to the parent, while you want to have the column to have a height relative to it's own height. And now kicks in the classic padding trick; give the element a bottom-padding and make it's child 100% the height of it's parent, like so:

```
.parent { width: 25%; padding-bottom: 25%; } /* .col-md-3 in your case */
.child { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

So now we have perfectly square elements, with the images as a background. This would normally suffice, because with `background-size: cover` the browser would make sure the image would span the whole div. But as you have images with white borders (to the side and the top/bottom) you'll have to zoom those to correct it. And the larger the borders (eg. for panorama images) the bigger the zoom size. That's why I have created the `.zoom` and `.zoom2` classes, which just increases the `background-size` property.

There you go!

Comment: here's what it look on my feed now :) just scroll at the bottom :)

http://campbrand.myshopify.com/
password : chough

Comment: I must say, it looks pretty sweet ;)